# Client Thread throwing a state exception and stopping C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, networking, server

I'm trying to create two client threads which are connected to a server. When there are two connections (Two entries in the `threadsArray`), I want the start to be announced. The code is never hitting the `threadRequest.annouceStart()` call however.

Through debugging I have determined that the first thread that is created is being stopped while the server is listening for another connection in the form of the second client. Is it this "freeze" as the server hangs waiting for another connection that is stopping the first thread?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    runServer();
}

static void runServer()
{
    TcpListener listener;
    Socket connection;
    Handler threadRequest;
    string defaultName = "";
    int defaultScore = 0;
    int i = 0;
    Thread[] threadsArray = new Thread[2];

    try
    {
        listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 43); 
        listener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Quiz Server launched");

        Console.WriteLine("A default user has been created for testing purposes");

        while(true) //main game loop
        {

                connection = listener.AcceptSocket();                      
               threadRequest = new Handler();

                threadsArray[i] = new Thread(() => threadRequest.clientInteraction(connection, teamInformation));
                threadsArray[i].Name = "Team" + (i + 1);

                threadsArray[i].Start();
                i++;


                if (threadsArray[1] != null)
                {
                    if (threadsArray[1].ThreadState == ThreadState.Running
                        && threadsArray[0].ThreadState == ThreadState.Running)
                    {
                        foreach (Thread thread in threadsArray)
                        {
                            threadRequest.announceStart(connection, teamInformation);
                        }
                    }
                }



        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

edit: added Handler class definition.

```
class Handler {

        public static string interactionType;
        public static string pTeamName;
        public static string pAnswer;

public void announceStart(Socket connection, ConcurrentDictionary<string, int> teamInformation)...

public void clientInteraction(Socket connection, ConcurrentDictionary<string, int> teamInformation)...

public static void parseStrings(StreamReader sr, string recievedLine, out string pTeamName,
            out string pAnswer)...

static void findInteractionType(out string interactionType, string clientString)...

}
```

Comment: Show your Handler class definition.

Comment: Move the declaration of `connection` inside of the while loop - otherwise you're replacing the existing value with a new one each time `listener.AcceptSocket()` returns. I assume the `clientInteraction()` method is some long-running method that doesn't immediately return? What is the `ThreadState` of each thread when you step through in the debugger.

Comment: @Mr.T In its present manifestation, the 'clientInteraction()' method isn't really that long at all, does the thread stop when that method returns? Because that might be what's causing it. The Threadstate of the first stops as soon as the second comes into existence which might be due to the aforementioned declaration position. Currently fiddling with it

Comment: Yes, Thread stops if executing method returns. You should run infinite loop in such method for avoid thread termination.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to Andrey Polyakov in comments.

"Thread stops if executing method returns. You should run infinite loop in such method for avoid thread termination" in regards to the `clientInteraction()` method.